# Why does my code add/delete records in SQL database but not update records?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

First off, I'm completely new at writing VB.Net and working in MS SQL Server. So please forgive any of my ignorance in what I'm about to ask.

I have been following along in a book, 'Beginning Visual Basic 2015', to learn VB.net.  More specifically how to connect VB.Net and an SQL Database.  I have built my own winforms app with modifications to the books code.

My issue is that while the code works for pulling data, adding new records and deleting records, it refuses to UPDATE any current records.  I have scoured the net trying to find solutions but have yet to come across anything helpful. (Apparently there's more than one way to interact with a db which makes finding the most applicable answers more difficult.)

As far as I can see my three procedures are (almost) identical. So there shouldn't be any issues... Correct?

I will include as much code as possible to help find my coding issue:

```vb
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

    objCommand.Connection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Members " &
    "(Active, [Last Name], [First Name], Suffix, Title, [LAN ID], [SOFT ID], Area1, Area2, Area3, [E-Mail], Phone) " &
    "VALUES(@Active, @LName, @FName, @Suffix, @Title, @LANID, @SOFTID, @Area1, @Area2, @Area3, @Email, @Phone);"

    With objCommand.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@Active", chkActive.Checked)
        '...[CODE OMITTED]
    End With

    Try
        objConnection.Open()
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch SqlExceptionErr As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(SqlExceptionErr.Message)
    Finally
        objConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim intPosition As Integer
    Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

    objCommand.Connection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Members WHERE ID = @ID;"

    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", BindingContext(objDataView).Current("ID"))

    Try
        objConnection.Open()
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch SqlExceptionErr As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(SqlExceptionErr.Message)
    Finally
        objConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim intPosition As Integer
    Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()

    objCommand.Connection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Members " &
        "SET Active = @Active, [Last Name] = @LName, [First Name] = @FName, Suffix = @Suffix, Title = @Title, [LAN ID] = @LANID, " &
        "[SOFT ID] = @SOFTID, Area1 = @Area1, Area2 = @Area2, Area3 = @Area3, [E-Mail] = @Email, Phone = @Phone " &
        "WHERE ID = @ID"

    With objCommand.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text)
        '...[CODE OMITTED]
    End With

    Try
        objConnection.Open()
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch SqlExceptionErr As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(SqlExceptionErr.Message)
    Finally
        objConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: @Cory Is there any error message that you are getting back? Have you printed out the `objCommand.CommandText` value to see what is being passed to the SQL Server?

Comment: Consider flipping to the chapter(s) related to *Debugging The Code You've Written* and using that knowledge on this problem.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Do you see an exception error?

Comment: .AddWithValue is not the best way to add parameters. The .Add method where you can specify the SQLDataType is better. I see you are sending the ID from a text box. This could cause a problem if this goes off to the server as a string when the server is expecting an integer.

Comment: @Mary THANK YOU - It should have been obvious, but I'm still struggling with the change from VBA - where Int and String are closer related - and VB.net where they are more literal.  Using `Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text)` was the solution.

Comment: @tarheel - No, there were no error messages and the CommandText looked good - at least to an untrained eye.  I will need to figure out a way to catch when the database does not "accept" an update.

Comment: @Mary - I have also tried the `.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(txtID.Text)` and got that to work as well.  One thing I noticed - that was confusing - is that I have the textbox that stores the "ID" hidden.  I didn't realize that if an object is not visible it will not store data.  That is also different from VBA.  Now working on how to pull the ID from the dataset instead of using a textbox.

Comment: @Cory I have stored primary keys in hidden labels before. I don't think a textbox should be any different. Try making it visible just for a test.

Comment: @Mary - I did, that’s what tipped me off. When it was visible it would pull the value, when it was not visible it would pull null.

Comment: @Cory I tried this just now and it works fine for me.  TextBox1.Text = "somevalue"
        Debug.Print(TextBox1.Text)